# Event manager - this undefined in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to create a custom javascript EventManager class and add some callback functions. But when the callback function is called, the 'this' object in the function is undefined. I looked at [Custom Javascript EventManager - please help me complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713187/custom-javascript-eventmanager-please-help-me-complete), but this doesn't answer my questions completely.

Why is this and this.name undefined in this.onEvent? Please help, thank you.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/fswfv/3/

```
function arEventManager()   {

    this.callbacks = {};            

    this.addCallback = function(eventCategory, fn) {
        if (!this.callbacks[eventCategory]) {
            this.callbacks[eventCategory] = [];
        }
        if (fn instanceof Function) {
            this.callbacks[eventCategory].push(fn);
        }
        return this;
    }, // addCallback

    this.dispatchEvent = function(eventCategory, params) {
        // Callback-Funktion(en) ausloesen
        for (var iC = 0, lC = this.callbacks[eventCategory].length; iC < lC; iC++) {
            console.log( this.callbacks[eventCategory][iC] );
            this.callbacks[eventCategory][iC](params);
        }
    } // dispatchEvent              
};

function arPerson() {
    this.name;
    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    this.getName = function() {
        return (this.name);
    },
    this.onEvent = function(p2) {
        alert('this.name = ' + this.name + ' / ' + 'p2.name = ' + p2.name);

    }
};


var eventManager = new arEventManager;

var Thomas = new arPerson();    
Thomas.setName('Thomas');

var Mike = new arPerson();  
Mike.setName('Mike');   

eventManager.addCallback("myEvent", Mike.onEvent);

function test() {
    eventManager.dispatchEvent('myEvent', Thomas);
}
```

Comment: A new function creates a new scope, with a different `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make name variable private?

Javascript (arPerson)

```
function arPerson() {
    var name;
    this.setName = function(nm) {
        name = nm;
    },
    this.getName = function() {
    return (name);
    },
    this.onEvent = function(p2) {
        alert('this.name = ' + name + ' / ' + 'p2.name = ' + p2.getName());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't use `call` or `apply` when you invoke the function, and you call it without a context. For example:

- `x.func()` calls `x.func` such that within the function `this` refers to `x`.
- `var func = x.func; func();` calls `x.func` with no specified value for `this`.
- `x.func.call(y);` calls `x.func` such that within the function `this` refers to `y`.

You can bind a context to the function by using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which you'll need to SHIM for browser compatibility:

```
eventManager.addCallback("myEvent", Mike.onEvent.bind(Mike));
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fswfv/4/)